# iOS 14 green dot is always visible after accessing camera with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, mobile, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ios14

I know "A green indicator  means either the camera or the camera and the microphone are being used by an app on your iPhone." I already dismissed the UIImagePickerController instance. I want to remove the green dot. but i don't know how. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the code. Seems like it is retained.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Thank you for your answer. But it is't retained. The UIImagePickController is dealloced.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know the reason. I use the runtime to record the VC. In the 'viewWillAppear' method, I add it to an array. In the 'viewWillDisappear', I remove it from the array. But CAMImagePickerCameraViewController doesn't call the viewWillDisappear method when dismissing. So.......